# Latex: Table: Define column width relatively

Tags: tables, pdftex, columns, relative

With this code I can divide all 4 columns in equal withs.

```latex
{@{}*{4}{p{.25\textwidth}@{}}}
```

How can I say (for example):

```
column 1: 20 %
column 2: 30 %
column 3: 25 %
column 4: 25 %
```

> Please give a fully compilable code.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[b!] %Label
    \centering
    \caption[Caption]{Caption.}
    \label{tab:Label}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}*{4}{p{.25\textwidth}@{}}}
        \toprule
        A   & B     & C     & D     \\ \midrule
        A1  & B1    & C1    & D1    \\
        A2  & B2    & C2    & D2    \\
        A3  & B3    & C3    & D3    \\
        A4  & B4    & C4    & D4    \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Please don't be surprised about A, B, C, D -- I have anonymized the data.

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please give a fully compilable code.

Comment: @AndréC Is this example now suitable?

Comment: It's perfect now :-)

Comment: Can anybody help me please? @AndréC ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[hb] %Label
    \centering
    \caption[Caption]{Caption.}
    \label{tab:Label}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}*{4}{p{.25\textwidth}@{}}}
        \toprule
        A   & B     & C     & D     \\ \midrule
        A1  & B1    & C1    & D1    \\
        A2  & B2    & C2    & D2    \\
        A3  & B3    & C3    & D3    \\
        A4  & B4    & C4    & D4    \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[b!hb] %Label
    \centering
    \caption[Caption]{Caption.}
    \label{tab:Label}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\dimexpr0.20\textwidth-\tabcolsep}
                       p{\dimexpr0.30\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}
                       p{\dimexpr0.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}
                       p{\dimexpr0.25\textwidth-\tabcolsep}
                    @{}}
        \toprule
        A   & B     & C     & D     \\ \midrule
        A1  & B1    & C1    & D1    \\
        A2  & B2    & C2    & D2    \\
        A3  & B3    & C3    & D3    \\
        A4  & B4    & C4    & D4    \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The first table is your original table, the second contain desired solution (if I correctly understood your question). Note: in calculation of desired width (as fraction of equation width) you need to consider `\tabcolsep`, i.e. distances between cell's content and column border. In the first and the last column are this distance removed by `@{}` on beginning and on the end of the column respectively.

[image]

(red lines indicate text border)

Comment: Thank you very much @Zarko , it worked exactly as I expected it!!

Comment: @matt, you are welcome, now I add short explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I propose to do that with `tabularx`, using the syntax `>{\hsize=coeff\hsize}X`, where the coefficients are proportional to 20, 30,25 and 25 respectively, with the constraint is that the sum of the coefficients be equal to the number of `X` columns (4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!] %Label
    \centering
    \caption[Caption]{Caption.}
    \label{tab:Label}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\hsize=0.8\hsize}X >{\hsize=1.2\hsize}XXX}
        \toprule
        A & B & C & D \\ \midrule
        A1 & B1 & C1 & D1 \\
        A2 & B2 & C2 & D2 \\
        A3 & B3 & C3 & D3 \\
        A4 & B4 & C4 & D4 \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]